# How can I know when a file is downloaded from a generic handler?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using a generic handler (ashx) to download an excel file from the client side like this:

```
window.location.href = '../../Handlers/hReportesAudiencias.ashx?OPCION=' + OPCION;
```

Sometimes the file is very big so it takes much time and I want to show a message (or something) saying "loading", "please wait" or something like that.

My problem is that I dont know when the file is downloaded and I have to hide the message.

Any ideas?

Note: I'm using IE8, and I have to do that because of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add logic to the handler to store the download progress in the session and then create another ajax method to query for that status from the download page on a timer.

When the download status changes to "complete" your ajax method will be able to trigger the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the file with an ajax request and show a message when it's completed.